# Clear a range of cells in Sheets using a checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, spreadsheet

I'm creating spreadsheet board games with my students, and one is making a tic-tac-toe game.  They tried adding a checkbox to clear a range for another round.

I know this will involve a specific App Script, but I am not sure which one and how to tell it to use the true/false with the checkbox and how to clear a specific range.

[Here is a copy of the sheet I am using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Htmssza7pUCawj6wKKmPpuEtL_IkWpkr-yRGYyp5i_c/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Game Board" && cell.getA1Notation() == "D5" && cell.isChecked()){
    // Clear Cell C2:E4
    activeSheet.getRange("C2:E4").clearContent();
    // reset checkbox
    cell.setValue(false);
  }
}
```

### What it does?

- Use [onEdit() Simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en#onedite) to call clear the board when the checkbox in Cell `D5` was checked.
- Get the current [spreadsheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) using the event object `e.source` and the [range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) using `e.range`.
- Get the active sheet using `getActiveSheet()`. Check if the modified cell is in sheet `Game Board`, check if the modified cell is in cell `D5` and lastly, check if the checkbox was checked using `isChecked()`.
- Clear the content of range `C2:E4` using `clearContent()` then reset the checkbox to `false`

### Output:

[image]